# Internal representation of the body of a rule using a defined operator (- <)

Tags: prolog, operators

I have a text document with the following statements:

```
spare_time -< ~busy.
~busy -< ~working.
~working.
```

and in my program prolog I define the operators:

```
:-op(1101,xfx,-<).  
:-op(1101,xfx,<-). 
:-op(190,fx,~).
```

what I intend to do is to read the text file and through assertz / 1 predicate statements with the form spare_time -< [~busy], that is, to convert the elements of the rule body into a list of elements. When reading the file and using process/1 predicate:

```
readFileSee(InputFile) :- seeing(OldStream),
                      see(InputFile),
                      repeat,
                      read(Term),
                      ( Term == end_of_file -> ! ; 
                        process(Term),fail

                      ),nl,

                      write('archivo cargado sin errores'),
                      seen,
                      see(OldStream).

process(Head-<Body):-format(atom(A),"~w",Body), 
                 atomic_list_concat(L,',',A), 
                 assertz([Head,'-<'|L]),
                 write(Head),write(-<),write(L),nl,!.
process(Atom):-assert(Atom),write(Atom),nl,!.
```

now, the process/1 predicate shows the following:

```
?- readFileSee('programasPrueba/test.delp').
spare_time-<[~busy]
~busy-<[~working]
~working

archivo cargado sin errores
true.
```

so I understand that the statements are inserted nicely. The problem arises when I try to define the following predicates:

```
argu(X):-[X,'-<'|Args], revC(Args),!.
argu(X):-X,!.


revC([H|B]):-[H,'-<'|Args],revC(Args), revC(B).
revC([H|[]]):-[H,'-<'|Args],revC(Args).
revC([H|B]):-H,revC(B).
revC([H|[]]):-H.
```

i have this problem when consulting argu(spare_time):

```
?- argu(spare_time).
ERROR: revC/1: Undefined procedure: '~busy'/0
Exception: (11) '~busy' ?
```

However, when I query by argu(~ busy) i have a result, so i guess i have a problem with the internal representation of the body elements of the rule i defined in the text document. Sorry for the extension.

Comment: Just an aside: `[H|[]]` is the same as just saying, `[H]`.

Comment: What happens if you try, `argu(~busy)` without the space?

Comment: I have already corrected the list [H | []]. The query continues to throw this error: ?- argu(~busy).
ERROR: revC/1: Undefined procedure: '~working'/0
   Exception: (9) '~working' ?

Comment: Right. My comment was "just an aside" and not intended to have a bearing on your error.

Comment: Yes I know :). Apparently, in the internal representation it is considered 'busy', and of course, this can not be unified with some head of some rule (which if it is is ~ busy as head of a rule).

Comment: When I tried your code with SWI Prolog, querying `argu(surf)` resulted in, *ERROR: argu/1: Undefined procedure: surf/0*, and querying `argu(~ busy)` resulted in *ERROR: revC/1: Undefined procedure: '~working'/0*.

Comment: I sorry, the consult is argu(spare_time).     This is what is in the text document (spare_time - <~busy)